# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS fully freezing while installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, freeze, amd-graphics

**For context:**
Specs:
AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile gfx, 8gb RAM, 512gb SSD

My laptop was working with dual boot Windows 11 + Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS previously, but had some issues with the integrated graphics and wasn't displaying any image, and after an APU reballing, it now works in Windows 11 perfectly, but freezes instantly while trying to boot/install ubuntu (also broken when trying to use Linux Mint).

I tried all the GRUB boot settings (nomodeset, noapic, nouveau.noaccel=1, etc..) but only one of them worked, **acpi=off**, which fixed the graphics freezing issue, but caused another issue with disk partitions not being detected during the Ubuntu installation, which means I still can't install it.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Edit: Tried Ubuntu 22.10 and 16.04, both didn't work either and have the same issue.

Comment: What is "APU reballing"?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but something about unsoldering the APU (which in this case is the integrated GPU of the CPU) and replacing it.

Comment: @Pilot6: Reballing a chip means that you unsolder it, clean it and make new dots of solder where they are supposed to be. Then you resolder the chip ( with a heatgun ) onto the pcb. This is done to make sure that all the connections are made. ( Problem is that you cannot see if all the connectios are made. But as it is working on another OS you would conclude that it is correctly connected. )

Comment: Does a newer release like 22.10 or the development release 23.04 (which isn't supported, but would be interesting to test as it has newer kernel) work?

Comment: @popey tried it out, got the same issues. Freezing when booting with default GRUB parameters and didn't freeze, but couldnt detect disk partitions when using `acpi=off